# duplicates in the ListView Bluetooth

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

First sorry for my English it is something bad.
Now i am currently programming an application and there is a problem with the list.
I always get duplicates in my list after searching for Devices, when i search again,I get the same devices again. I have to tried to use sets but i get still duplicates.
I don't know how to solve this problem.
Please help someone with Code.
Thank you advance.

Here is my Code:

`

```
    public void Init(){
    foundDevicesSet = new HashSet<String>();
    tBtn = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    availableDivce = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);    
    bluetoohOff =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);        
    DeviceList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);    
    searchButton =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);           
    deviceNameAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);         
    DeviceList.setAdapter(deviceNameAdapter);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String action = intent.getAction();             

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {                                  
            BluetoothDevice newDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);                    
            if (newDevice.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {                       
                foundDevicesSet.add(newDevice.getName() + "|" + newDevice.getAddress());                        

                for(String one : foundDevicesSet){                      
                deviceNameAdapter.add(one);
                }


                }                               
                }
                }       
    };      



}   `
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm on a Bluetooth project too and I was facing this same problem 5 minutes ago, not with paired devices but with available devices around. Here is the code that made it work without any duplicate device. I must say I'm using a ListView to show them and an ArrayAdapter aswell:

```
if (mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getPosition((device.getName()+ "\n" + device.getAddress())) == -1)
{
    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                  
}
```

This instruction looks for this `device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress()` in the ArrayAdapter because that's is the format I use to save it in. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Each time a new device is found, you're adding the entire devices set to the adapter again... So, either:

- Call `deviceNameAdapter.add(newDevice.getName() + "|" + newDevice.getAddress());` instead of adding it to the set.
- Call `deviceNameAdapter.clear()` before adding the entire set to the adapter.